# Views show / hide filter via dropdown

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to show / hide filters via a dropdown select. What I want to achieve is, that there is a dropdown with all my filters, and only the one I select in dropdown will show up.

I've found the [Composite Views Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/composite_views_filter)  module. But this works only with one group. If I have two Dropdowns to select filters, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned Module [Composite Views Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/composite_views_filter) was extended by it's maintainer. It is still in patch-test-phase, but it is working now to bring in as much filter groups as you like.

> Allows you to create one filter condition that enables a bunch of filter conditions. Sometimes one condition isn't enough for your filter, but you still want the user to be able to change the filter (group).